# Symfony2 cannot enable profiler from test

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm testing a registration case where the user fill a form, then submit-it and get an email with his credentials while being logged and redirected to his personal space.

So I need to check the sent email to verify the credentials, I setup my config_test.yml like this

```
framework:
    profiler:
        enabled: true
        collect: true
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file        

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: true
```

Everything works fine I successfully recover the email content, but I want to disable the profiller collection on my other test cases so I setup the "collect: " parameters to false and added a call to enable the profiler from the test case (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/profiling.html) but it doesn't work.

A snippet of my code:

```
public function testRegistration()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->enableProfiler();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/registration');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());

    $boutonForm = $crawler->selectButton('InscriptionParticulier_envoyer');
        $formulaire = $boutonForm->form(array(
            'InscriptionParticulier[prenom]' => 'Hermes',
            'InscriptionParticulier[nom]' => 'Conrad',
    ));
    $client->submit($formulaire);

    var_dump((boolean)$client->getKernel()->getContainer()->has('profiler'));
    var_dump((boolean)$client->getProfile());
}
```

With the collect parameter (from config)  set to true I get :

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

With the collect parameter (from config) set to false I get :

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

The profiler seems to be set but I can't get it, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the form submission was causing an unexpected redirection.

So i splited my test in two substask :

**Test of the form values:**

*Select form -> fill the fields -> submit -> follow redirect -> get and analyse the results*

```
public function testInscriptionParticulierFormOk()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/compte/inscription/particulier');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());

    $boutonForm = $crawler->selectButton('InscriptionParticulier_envoyer');
    $formulaire = $boutonForm->form(array(
        'InscriptionParticulier[prenom]' => 'Philip',
        'InscriptionParticulier[nom]' => 'J. Fry',
        'InscriptionParticulier[email][first]' => 'philip@planetexpress.com',
        'InscriptionParticulier[email][second]' => 'philip@planetexpress.com',
        'InscriptionParticulier[captcha]' => '12345',
    ));
    $client->submit($formulaire);

    //Enable redirects
    $client->followRedirect();

    //Test result on redirected page
    $this->assertRegExp('/Bienvenue sur le site, accueil/', $client->getResponse()->getContent());        
}
```

**Test of the mail content:**

*Send a post request with the form data -> enable profiler -> get and analyse the mail content*

```
public function testInscriptionParticulierFormEmail()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->enableProfiler();

    $csrfToken = $client->getContainer()->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('InscriptionParticulier');

    $formData = 
        array('InscriptionParticulier' => array(
            '_token' => $csrfToken,
            'prenom' => 'Amy', 
            'nom' => 'Wong',
            'email' => array(
                'first' => 'amy@planetexpress.com', 
                'second' => 'amy@planetexpress.com'
            ),
            'captcha' => '12345'
        )
    );

    $client->request('POST', '/compte/inscription/particulier', $formData);

    //Get email data
    $mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');

    //Email sent?
    $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

    //Get some messages
    $collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages();
    $message = $collectedMessages[0];

    //Check the mail content
    $this->assertInstanceOf('Swift_Message', $message);
    $this->assertEquals('Bienvenue sur le site !', $message->getSubject());
    $this->assertEquals('xxx@xxx.com', key($message->getTo()));
    //Check if the mail have the credentials
    $this->assertRegExp('/Identifiant : [a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]{2,5}/', $message->getBody());
    $this->assertRegExp('/Mot de passe : [a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $message->getBody());
}
```